# Locating the typed version of Hoàng Xuân Sính's thesis on Gr-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, paper-request

Hoàng Xuân Sính was a Vietnamese student of Grothendieck who defended her thesis on Gr-categories (now called weak 2-groups). The thesis, handwritten and in French, can be found at

https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/lexmath/kuenzer/sinh.html

According to the nLab, there exists also a typed version (perhaps in English?):

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ho%C3%A0ng+Xu%C3%A2n+S%C3%ADnh

Can anyone provide a link to that version?

Comment: a summary in English (handwritten) is at https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/lexmath/kuenzer/thesis_sinh_summary_sinh.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TeXed version can be found on

[https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/SinhThesis.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/SinhThesis.pdf)

Cristian David Gonzalez Avilés is the author of the TeX version. For reasons unknown to me, the TeX version numbers the theorems/propositions etc. differently than in the handwritten original.

Comment: I'm a little uncomfortable calling someone who TeXed a previously existing handwritten thesis the "author" of the TeXed version of that thesis.